# IE img doesn't stretch li

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-lists, image, expand

I have [this code here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonur/mTKKM/2/). If you open it a browser other than IE, then you would be able to see that the 3rd and 5th `li` of the `ul.submenu` have also an `img` inside. In IE unfortunately it's not displayed on the 3rd `li`, and it's going underneath like in a different line as if it lacks floats. Normally, the `img` should just expand the `li` as in the rest browsers.

I have tried changing the `display` property of both `li` and `img`, as well as various `margin` and `padding` combinations of the `img` but with no luck.

Anyone knows why this happens and what should I do to reach the proper result? Any help will be very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Number 1 rule of styling lists**: use `display:block` on the `A`-tag and put all styling there (other than things for positioning/hiding/showing your lists).

See my tutorail: [I love lists](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/).

Comment: OK but I don't have `a` tags! :)

Comment: Then how will users click on your menu?

Comment: The specifications of the project require the whole `li` to be clickable (the whole green area) so there will be `javascript: onclick` events. At least that was a solution I came up with. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: That's a terrible design idea. Not only will the application be unusable for people with disabilities but it will also be impossible for any search engine to index your site.

Comment: "The whole green area" will be the `a` element if you follow @Diodeus advice. Because `li` will have the same size as its child `a`, that's the trick.

Comment: OK I will remake that contain an `a` and an `img`. Will I have to include the `img` inside the `a` for both to be links?

Comment: No, you set the image as a CSS background for the A. See my tutorial section about backgrounds.